# Name for function of the form $f \colon (0, 1) \to (0, 1)$

Tags: functions, terminology

I'm looking for a name for a class of functions $y = f(x)$ that satisfies the following:

- $f$ is defined for x in $(0, 1)$,
- the output $f(x)$ is in $(0, 1)$.

Typical simple examples are:

- $f(x) := x\quad\quad$ (a linear response)
- $f(x) := x^{2.2}\quad$ (a 2.2 gamma curve)

It should intuitively represent: *what comes out if this goes in?* In case of a simple $y=x$ function, the function has no effect.

I'm developing some software where the user has to interact with this type of curve in a 1-by-1 box. I'm trying to come up with names:

- transfer function (not correct, as this is a term from signal processing, related to transform analysis).
- response function

Anyone that can come up with a good name for these type of functions?

---

**UPDATE**: Some more suggestions I came up with:

- Unit Function
- Box Function
- Unit Box Function
- Unit Square Function
- Unit Transformation Function

Comment: I think it depends on the context in which it is used.

Comment: Never heard these functions have a name... What about you call them *$1$-by-$1$ box functions*?

Comment: I have the follwing suggestion: call them FRED-functions.

Comment: Functions from a set to the same set are sometimes called transformations.

Comment: @Edu: Yeah, that sounds reasonable, but makes for a hideous classname and filename in this software project: `Curve_1by1` or something :P So I was hoping for something nicer.

Comment: @rubik: My specific context is a Photoshop like Curves function, like RGB curves, or Luma curve for example.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, it is an _automorphic_ function on $(0,1)$.  In your specific case, what would you think about calling it a (unit) _tuning_ function, or tuning _curve_?

Comment: _Tuning_ function is good, or maybe calibration.